# Twitter PIN-based auth

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

So I am busy with building an app for twitter, and I want people to auth using PIN. (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based).

To show people the PIN code, I need to use this: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize

There example says:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=*

So I tried it with my 'Access Token' (d) but it says the request token is invalid. What am I doing wrong?

(Full url is https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=3459712042-A8kkuqFqmhKs9qm9cGjEaGAwCWyik81cmE94HCD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found it myself.
I first needed to make a POST to request_token

```
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token
```